# ASP.Net User Role Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, role

I have in my project a user role hierarchy by pages but I need more, imagine 2 roles they can open the `Adduser.aspx` page they can see here packages the packages are sending by companies and the companies have a NUMBER.

I will say when the user of this company is opened the page I will show only his packages to him. But the difficult part is I am writing too much code ..

Code examples :

```
   public string NUMBER
    {
        get
        {
            return
                (string)CacheManagement.GetCache(
                    string.Format("{0}{1}", "EdistraintCache", CurrentSession.CurrentUser.UserId), GetNUMBER);
        }
    }
```

and I have if statemnt in 15 pages like this

```
 if (Enum.GetValues(typeof(UmRoles))
                .Cast<UmRoles>()
                .Any(umRole => CurrentUser.UserRoles.Any(x => x.RolKey.Contains(umRole.GetStringValue()))))
        {
            //... 
        }
```

*Have you any **suggest** code or **idea** for writing better code ?.*

Comment: hello everyone I have found a solution, it's easy solution , you should your page or your controller  inherit (page,usercontrol) .You can control only write once your condition.On your all pages where you inhert your page or usercontrol load will work.